# Showing an inequality using the taylor expansion on an integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, taylor-expansion

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\int_0^x\arctan(\sin(t))dt$. Show that $$-\frac{1}{2}x^3 \leq f(x)-\frac{1}{2}x^2 \leq 0, \text{when $x\in(0,\pi)$}$$

Since the integral is complicated I resorted to using the maclaurin series for the function. So by the definition:
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n \implies f(x)=\int_0^0\arctan(\sin(t))dt+\arctan(\sin(0))x+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\cos(0)}{\sin^2(0)+1}{x^2}+...$$
If calculate some of the first terms we end up with $f(x)=0+0x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+...$ Here is where I'm having some trouble, I don't know how I should include the remainder in this sum to show the inequality.

Comment: How about computing the Maclaurin series for f’ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One inequality is trivial: over $\mathbb{R}^+$ we have $\arctan(\sin t)\leq \sin t\leq t$, hence $\int_{0}^{x}\arctan(\sin t)\,dt \leq \int_{0}^{x}t\,dt = \frac{x^2}{2}.$

For the lower bound, we may consider that $\arctan(u)\geq u-\frac{u^3}{3}$ for any $u\in[0,1]$, hence

$$ \arctan(\sin t) \geq \sin(t)-\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(t) $$

and

$$ \int_{0}^{x}\arctan(\sin t)\,dt \geq \frac{28-27\cos(x)-\cos(3x)}{36} \geq \frac{3}{4}\left(1-\cos x\right)=\frac{3}{2}\sin^2\frac{x}{2}$$
which is much sharper than $\text{LHS}\geq \frac{x^2-x^3}{2}$.